# Firebase Storage: User not permitted to access object despite public rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I am new to Firebase storage. I made a simple app that should download a file from Firebase.
The download fails every time with the following error:

```
StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
User does not have permission to access this object.
Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
```

These are my rules on Firebase:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/***.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I already also tried to enable anonymous authentification, but this doesn't change anything despite the login is successful.

EDIT: This is my java code:

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener((Activity) context, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {...}


FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
//Create a storage reference from our app
storageRef = firebaseStorage.getReference();
contentDir = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "\\content\\testfile.txt");
storageRef.getFile(contentDir).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Downloading files from the storage root is either not supported or is not covered by the default security rule. (Maybe `match /{allPaths=**}` doesn't include root?)  Move the file to some location other than the root:

```
FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
storageRef = firebaseStorage.getReference("anyPath");
```

---

If for testing you want to allow public access to you storage bucket, use these rules, copied from the [Storage Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules).  The rule posted by j_h_o_m_o is safer, limiting access to signed-in users:

```
// Anyone can read or write to the bucket, even non-users of your app.
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/***.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Also check that your bucket name matches what you see in the Firebase Console.  For example, if the Storage Files tab shows `gs://project-12345.appspot.com`, your rule would start:

```
match /b/project-12345.appspot.com/o {
```

Comment: @FlorianBaader:  Make sure the bucket name is correct.  I get `Code: -13021` when the bucket name is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I checked the bucket name but there are no spelling errors ... this is really frustrating (I am trying to get it working since 3 days)

Comment: It will take me a minute to find the explanation for this.  I recall seeing it.  There is a restriction on reading files at the storage root.  Move the file to some arbitrary path and will work.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: this will let anyone access your storage authenticated or not
try changing your rules to the storage to this

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this checks if the user is authenticated or not, by default on storage and database authentication is required. Try and see if you can access your database with the following rules if not then paste your error logs

Comment: I just try to download the file. I wanted to secure it afterwards. But anyway I tried your solution and it didn't work